# Best way to unit test classes using streams?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, stream

I am currently writing some code to try to experiment with separating and abstracting two parts of our storage strategies at work.  We currently use JSON format stored into a file and then retrieve it as our persistent storage.  I am trying to experiment with separating the two concepts:

1) Concept one keeps the serialization separate from the storage type

2) Concept two keeps the storage type separate from the serialization strategy.

I found a good way that works doing some research on various threads, such as using TextWriter/TextReader instead of directly using Files so that any Stream type can be used (FileStream/MemoryStream/etc) so that the unit tests can be done without files.  However, I am running into a problem since the TextWriter/TextReader classes which wrap the streams automatically close and dispose of the streams when they are themselves disposed, which is what I want in practice, but gets me stuck in unit testing.

Here is the code I have so far... this is for concept 1, the serialization process.  Here are the interfaces for it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interface for a serializer which reads from a stream and creates a type
/// </summary>
public interface IInSerializer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Load type from a stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool Load(TextReader reader);
}

/// <summary>
/// Interface for writing a type out into a stream
/// </summary>
public interface IOutSerializer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Save to the stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool Save(TextWriter writer);
}

/// <summary>
/// Helper interface which provides interface <see cref="IInSerializer"/> 
/// and <see cref="IOutSerializer"/> for both reading/writing
/// </summary>
public interface IInOutSerializer : IInSerializer, IOutSerializer
{
}
```

Here is an abstract implementation of the serializer for JSON format:

```
/// <summary>
/// Implementation of <see cref="IInOutSerializer"/> which serializes into JSON format
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type to be serialized</typeparam>
public abstract class JSONSerializer<T> : IInOutSerializer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Source of serialization
    /// </summary>
    public T Source { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provided by very specific type to load the Jobject into type T
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="jObject"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected abstract bool LoadJObject(JObject jObject);
    /// <summary>
    /// Provided by very specific type to save type T into a Jobject
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="jObject"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected abstract bool Serialize(JObject jObject);

    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="IInOutSerializer.Load"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Load(TextReader reader)
    {
        using (var json = new JsonTextReader(reader))
        {
            var jObject = JToken.ReadFrom(json) as JObject;
            if (jObject != null)
                return LoadJObject(jObject);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="IInOutSerializer.Save"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Save(TextWriter writer)
    {
        var jObject = new JObject();
        if (Serialize(jObject))
        {
            using (var json = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
            {
                json.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                jObject.WriteTo(json);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is one of the concrete types for serializing my class MetroLineDetails:

```
public class MetroLineJSONSerializationStrategy : JSONSerializer<MetroLineDetails>
{
    private class MetroLineHelper : IMetroLine, IMetroLineWritable
    {
        public string DestinationStation
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Color LineColor
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public char LineLetter
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool SaturdayService
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string SourceStation
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool SundayHolidayService
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static explicit operator MetroLineDetails(MetroLineHelper source)
        {
            return new MetroLineDetails(source.Name, source.LineColor, source.SourceStation, source.DestinationStation, source.SaturdayService, source.SundayHolidayService);
        }
    }
    protected override bool LoadJObject(JObject jObject)
    {
        var helper = new MetroLineHelper();
        jObject.Read(nameof(MetroLineDetails.Name), (t) => (string)t, (v) => helper.Name = v);
        jObject.Read(nameof(MetroLineDetails.LineLetter), (t) => (char)t, (v) => helper.LineLetter = v);
        jObject.Read(nameof(MetroLineDetails.SourceStation), (t) => (string)t, (v) => helper.SourceStation = v);
        jObject.Read(nameof(MetroLineDetails.DestinationStation), (t) => (string)t, (v) => helper.DestinationStation = v);
        jObject.Read(nameof(MetroLineDetails.SaturdayService), (t) => (bool)t, (v) => helper.SaturdayService = v);
        jObject.Read(nameof(MetroLineDetails.SundayHolidayService), (t) => (bool)t, (v) => helper.SundayHolidayService = v);

        var color = jObject.Read(nameof(MetroLineDetails.LineColor), (t) => (JObject)t);
        helper.LineColor = color.ToColor();

        Source = (MetroLineDetails)helper;

        return true;
    }

    protected override bool Serialize(JObject jObject)
    {
        jObject.Add(nameof(MetroLineDetails.Name), Source.Name);
        jObject.Add(nameof(MetroLineDetails.LineLetter), Source.LineLetter);
        jObject.Add(nameof(MetroLineDetails.SourceStation), Source.SourceStation);
        jObject.Add(nameof(MetroLineDetails.DestinationStation), Source.DestinationStation);
        jObject.Add(nameof(MetroLineDetails.SaturdayService), Source.SaturdayService);
        jObject.Add(nameof(MetroLineDetails.SundayHolidayService), Source.SundayHolidayService);
        jObject.Add(nameof(MetroLineDetails.LineColor), Source.LineColor.ToJObject());

        return true;
    }
}
```

And now here are my storage type interfaces:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interface for the storage medium
/// </summary>
public interface IStorageMedium
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Save the information in the serializer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serializer"></param>
    void Save(IOutSerializer serializer);
    /// <summary>
    /// Load the information to the serializer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serializer"></param>
    void Load(IInSerializer serializer);
}
```

And the type specifically for files:

```
/// <summary>
/// Implementation of <see cref="IStorageMedium"/> which stores into a file
/// </summary>
public class FileStorageMedium : IStorageMedium
{
    private readonly string _fileName;

    public FileStorageMedium(string fileName)
    {
        _fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void Save(IOutSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Truncate))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                serializer.Save(writer);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Load(IInSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                serializer.Load(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in each layer I want to follow best practices and make sure each method closes and flushes the stream for the caller and not leave things open for the sake of unit testing (I know I could probably change the code to not close the streams, but I don't think that is appropriate).

So, now, using the ideas I've found on the forums to not have anything tied specifically to file streams to help with unit testing, I'm still running into problems finding the best way to unit test this.  Here is the unit test I am trying to write:

```
[TestClass]
public class MetroLine
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSerialize()
    {
        var serializer = new MetroLineJSONSerializationStrategy();
        serializer.Source = new MetroLineDetails("A", Colors.Blue, "LA Union Station", "San Bernardino", true, true);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            serializer.Save(writer);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The stream is closed no matter what I do in the serializer.Save() call since that method uses a disposable which closes the stream (as I believe it should to prevent leaks).  The problem is, I can no longer unit test the stream in any way to test whether any of this works.  I get exceptions thrown saying you cannot access closed streams anymore, which makes sense.  But how can I test the contents of my stream in any meaningful way?

Comment: If I understand your code correctly you're only using TextReader and TextWriter in your interfaces. Do you know that the StreamWriter contains a [ctor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) that leaves the stream open after dispose? Maybe that helps. You're using a JsonTextWriter on top of the StreamWriter that seams not to be part of the .net framework. I don't know that class but StreamWriter and leaveOpen might work. Good luck.

Comment: @Verarind: Thanks for the reply!  I actually did not know that, but I think I found another workable solution that will work well enough for me.  I will post and consider the question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found GetBuffer on the MemoryStream which allows me to convert the raw buffer into a string and I can unit test the actual JSON blob however I want... here is what I wrote:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSerialize()
    {
        var serializer = new MetroLineJSONSerializationStrategy();
        serializer.Source = new MetroLineDetails("Inland Empire Line", Colors.Blue, 'A', "LA Union Station", "San Bernardino", true, true);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                serializer.Save(writer);
            }
            var bytes = stream.GetBuffer();
            var json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            Assert.AreEqual('{', json[0]);
        }
    }
```

My hopes are someone will find this useful!